# MS Excel: Formula is not working Properly

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am newbie to Excel. I am trying to make Attendance Reports.Now, Reports will be calculated as per conditions which are as follows:

```
Min Range as 'C': 09:30
Max Range as 'D': 19:30
```

Let us consider, A as In and B as Out

```
a)If A>C and B<D, then B-A  For Eg: 10:00>09:30  and 19:00<19:30 then O/P is 09:00 
b)If A<C and B<D ,then B-C  For Eg: 09:00<09:30  and 19:00<19:30 then O/P is 09:30
c)If A>C and B>D, then D-A  For Eg: 10:30>09:30  and 20:00>19:30 then O/P is 08:00
d)If A<C and B>D, then D-C  For Eg: 09:00<09:30  and 20:00>19:30 then O/P is 10:00
```

Excel Formula:

```
  =IF(AND(B>=C,A<=D),B-A,
    IF(AND(A>=C,B>=D),H55-A,
    IF(AND(A<=C,B<=D),B-H54,
    IF(AND(A<=C,B>=D),"10:00","Wrong"))))
```

Now,Excel formula is working for some conditions, but for some conditions is not working. Please do suggest me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out.

```
=IF(AND(A>=C,B<=D),B-A,IF(AND(A<=C,B<=D),B-C,IF(AND(A>=C,B>=D),D-A,IF(AND(A<=C,B>=D),D-C,"Wrong"))))
```

Comment: Condition C) which you have given in question is wrong. 19:30 - 10:30 is 9:00 and not 8:00. My formula gives correct answer. Check again.

Answer (score 0):

The criteria described could be summarized as follows:

`In Time` cannot be earlier than `09:30` and `Out Time` cannot be later than `19:30`.

Therefore `In Time = IF(A<=C,C,A)` and `Out Time =IF(B>=D,D,B)`

The final formula should be `O/P = Out Time - In Time` then try this formula:

`=SUM(IF(B>=D,D,B),-IF(A<=C,C,A))`

Comment: Thanks for Your Answer, But Partially working.For Earlier than 09:30 and later than 19:30, it should show 10:00, not difference.

Comment: Earlier than 09:30 and later than 19:30 results to 10:00, as the difference between the latest hour to be computed minus the earliest hour to be computed (i.e 19:30 and 09:30 respectively) and the difference between this two is 10:00. As mentioned that's the criteria applied.